# sudo change default error message

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

I'm writing a bash script where I need some custom prompts.

```
sudo -p "Some custom prompt"
```

works like a charm, but how can I change de default message that pops up when a user enters te wrong password (if this is possible at all)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to change it but it requires to recompile `sudo`. You can then provide `--with-badpass-message` on configure step. See [sources](https://github.com/millert/sudo/blob/master/INSTALL#L602-L605) for reference.

If you cannot recompile sudo, I do not think it is possible.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of yes..
And since I'm on Mac OS I'm not gonna bother recompiling it.
Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it, but in the sudoers file you can put in:

> Default    badpass_message="your custom error message"

Answer (score 1):

you need to add badpass options to sudoers file

```
sudo vim /etc/sudoers
```

and after that just type this

```
Default badpass_message="error"
```